# Why is the http.request never getting the response?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying the `http.request` in node.  But my test script just never finishes.

- What is wrong?
- How can I debug this script?

Thx!

```
const http = require('http');
const parse_url = require('url').parse;

const srv = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('okay');
});
srv.listen(0);

const addr = srv.address();
const url = `http://localhost:${addr.port}`;
const url_obj = parse_url(url);

const option = {
  protocol: url_obj.protocol,
  host: url_obj.host,
  hostname: url_obj.hostname,
  port: addr.port,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};
console.log(option);
const req = http.request(option, (res) => {
  console.log('done');
  srv.close();
});

// below is only for debugging

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

req.on('socket', (socket) => {
  console.log('socket event');

  socket.on('data', function() {
    console.log('data', arguments);
  });
  socket.on('lookup', function() {
    console.log('lookup', arguments);
  });
  socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end', arguments);
  });

});
```

Here is the console output:

```
$ node t.js 
{ protocol: 'http:',
  host: 'localhost:43347',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 43347,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET' }
socket event
lookup { '0': null, '1': '127.0.0.1', '2': 4, '3': 'localhost' }
```

And the script never exit. Ideally it should exit upon `srv.close()`

Comment: What is the request? What console messages does the code print?

Comment: @Juhana `req` is the request.

Comment: No, I mean what kind of request are you making on the client. Sockets don't automatically close unless either party closes them; that's the whole idea of sockets.

Comment: @Juhana A http GET request, I guess

Comment: Well ok, if you're not specifically using sockets then this is the wrong approach. You shouldn't use `req.on('socket')` at all.

Comment: @Juhana I added those only for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed this sentence in the document

> Note that in the example req.end() was called. With http.request() one
>   must always call req.end() to signify that you're done with the
>   request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback